# Unique email in Google Datastore

Tags: go, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `User` entity containing an `Email` field. The `User` entity id is a [ULID](https://github.com/oklog/ulid), because I want to allow users to change their email addresses, but I want to ensure that the email address is unique on both a `CREATE` and an `UPDATE`.

I am using Datastore transactions. This is a code fragment:

```
ctx := context.Background()
k := datastore.NameKey("User", user.ID, nil)
_, err := client.RunInTransaction(ctx, func(t *datastore.Transaction) error {
    // other stuff that needs to be in transaction
    _, err = t.Put(k, user)
    return err
})

return err
```

The `Email` field is indexed. Is there any way to search the `User` entity for the current user's email address as part of the transaction?

`*datastore.Transaction` does not have a `GetAll` method, so I cannot run a query like this:

```
datastore.NewQuery("User").Filter("Email =", user.Email)
```

I'm afraid that using

```
client.GetAll(ctx, q, nil)
```

will not guarantee isolation within the transaction.

Comment: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Transaction.Get Please note the comment about the isolation level as well.

Comment: > All reads performed during the transaction will come from a single consistent snapshot.
It is not clear to me that the isolation applies if the query is not made through `t`. Maybe I'm overthinking it?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with datastore. Are you able to use the `Get` method to get a user by email in your scenario? Or will that only work for the ID field?

Comment: The `Get` expects a key, not a query.

Comment: Right, can you make a key `emailKey := datastore.NameKey("Email", user.Email, nil)`?

Comment: No. I do not have an entity (i.e. "table") named `Email`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot use a query as part of a transaction unless you are querying a specific entity group. Global queries are alway eventually consistent. However, to put everything in a single entity group would likely limit write throughput too much.

A workaround is you can have another Kind with entities that map email addresses to users. Then you can, in a transaction, check the email Entity and if it doesn't exist or it points to a bad location, set the email Entity and the user Entity all as a single transaction.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was thinking that the answer would be something along those lines. I guess when a user changes his/her email, I would also delete the "row" from `Email` that corresponds to the old value.