# How to enforce Uniqueness in a Property of a document field in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, unique

I have the following data as shown in the image.
I want to make sure that the username field is unique. How can I enforce that? Bear in mind that my document id is already unique and I don't want to use my username as the document ID

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to enforce unique values of fields in Firestore. The only uniqueness you can guarantee is the document IDs within a collection, so the solution is to create a new collection where the user names are used as document IDs.

This has been discussed a few times before, so I recommend checking out:

- [Firestore security rule to check if character username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016426/firestore-security-rule-to-check-if-character-username-already-exists/52017880#52017880)
- [Check a document field for a specific value in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372164/check-a-document-field-for-a-specific-value-in-cloud-firestore/49372447#49372447)
- [I want to make unique usernames in firebase/firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111638/i-want-to-make-unique-usernames-in-firebase-firestore), which shows some of the relevant security rules.
- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names)
- [Firestore unique index or unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543251/firestore-unique-index-or-unique-constraint/59892127#59892127), a more complete write-up with code and rules samples.
- [Cloud Firestore: Enforcing Unique User Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47405774/cloud-firestore-enforcing-unique-user-names/53032126#53032126)